# Google Analytics tracking not working in MS Edge v15

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics, microsoft-edge

I am using Google Analytics to track product impressions in my Rails 4 based web application. I have the following code in one of my erb files

```
  <script>
    <% list = 'Search Results: ' + search_params.values.join(", ") %>
    <% products.each.with_index(1) do |product, index| %>
      ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':       '<%= product.id %>',
        'name':     "<%= product.name %>",
        'list':     "<%= raw list %>",
        'brand':    "<%= raw product.brand_name %>",
        'category': "<%= raw product.adwords_category %>",
        'position': <%= index %>,
        'price':    '<%= product.price %>'
      });
      <% if index % 24 == 0 %>
        ga('send', 'event', 'Dummy Event', 'List Page', 'Product Impression', 1, {'nonInteraction': 1, 'useBeacon': true });
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    console.log('Sent search results to google analytics');
  </script>
```

This is working fine on browsers Chrome, Firefox, Safari, MS Edge v14 but is not working in MS Edge v15. In MS Edge v15, no data gets registered in Google Anaytics. I know that my script did execute because of the console.log that i added, but i dont see any data in Google Analytics.

What could be the reason behind this not working with Google Analytics in MS Edge v15 ?

Comment: Sounds weird i have pinged the Google Analytics team

Comment: I know this wont solve your problem but use GTM ...

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the suggestion. However using GTM is not an option i have at the moment. I would be more interested in knowing why this works on all browsers except MS Edge v15.

Comment: I was trying to use Google Analytics in a web extension and facing this error. Its crashing MS Edge, but it's working fine in Firefox.